# JavaFx How to make checkbox visible in tableColumnCell using cellFactory

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to add checkBox to tableCell but i dont know what to do to make checkBox visible when i use .setCellFactory

I want to achive this with cellFactory function ---> [checkBoxVisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPN9v.jpg)

when i want to make use of cellFactory checkBox are not visible
----> [wrong effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1w8P.jpg)

```
window1.setCellFactory(new BooleanColorCellFactory());
window2.setCellFactory(new BooleanColorCellFactory());
```

This is BooleanColorCellFactory Class

```
        @Override
        public TableCell<Server, CheckBox> call(TableColumn<Server, CheckBox> param) {

            return new TableCell<Server, CheckBox>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(CheckBox item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
//                  if(!empty) {
//                      setVisible(true);
//                      setEditable(true);
//                      getChildren().add(item);
//                  setText(item.toString());
//                      if(item.isSelected())
//                          setStyle(" -fx-background-color: Green");
//                      else
//                          setStyle(" -fx-background-color: RED");
                    }
//              }
            };
        }

    }
```

I have tried some things but nothing was working.

What i need to add in BooleanColorCellFactory to make this work ?

UPDATE:

So i was playing around and i manage to get step closer to solution by adding this into BooleanColorCellFactory Class

```
if(!getChildren().contains(item))
    getChildren().add(item);
```

but it is buggy and dont looks well and its added after i start scrolling(which is weird behavior for me)--> [click](https://imgur.com/a/09dCvhF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put a `Node` inside the item class unless you really need to. Furthermore never access the children of a `Control` directly unless you're writing a `Skin` for this `Control`.

You should instead add a `BooleanProperty` to the `Server` class:

```
private final BooleanProperty window1 = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

public boolean isWindow1() {
    return window1.get();
}

public void setWindow1(boolean value) {
    window1.set(value);
}

public BooleanProperty window1Property() {
    return window1;
}
```

```
TableColumn<Server, Boolean> window1;
```

```
Callback<TableColumn<Server, Boolean>, TableCell<Server, Boolean>> factory = new BooleanColorCellFactory();

// cellValueFactory returns property
window1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("window1"));
window1.setCellFactory(factory);

...

window2.setCellFactory(factory);
```

```
@Override
public TableCell<Server, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Server, Boolean> param) {

    return new TableCell<Server, Boolean>(){

        private final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

        {
            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                // save new value in row item
                WritableValue<Boolean> property = (WritableValue<Boolean>) getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue​(getIndex());
                property.setValue(newValue);
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
                setStyle(null);
            } else {
                setGraphic(checkBox);
                checkBox.setSelected(item);
                setStyle(item ? "-fx-background-color: Green" : "-fx-background-color: RED");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Procede accordingly for `window2`

Comment: <3 it works and i learned someting <3 i wish i could up vote you. <3

Comment: why checkBox is final ?

Comment: Why not? There should be at most one created per cell and just adding this keyword prevents accidentally reassigning the value. Furthermore it needs to be initialized.

Comment: Ok. I have noticed some weird behavior after implementing your code [here](https://imgur.com/a/L0RCQ2Y) you can see that when i checked only one box that is green on the screen after i scrolled up and returned down you can see that more then one checkbox is checked and cell is still green but now checked. Do you know what happened ? (there is more chekced boxes out of the screen)

Comment: Completely forgot about setting the selected state of the checkbox in `updateItem`, sorry, should be fixed now...

Comment: Yes now it is fine. <3

Comment: hmm... why re-invent the wheel ?  there's CheckBoxTableCell in core

Comment: Thanks for saying, CheckBoxTableCell  is better solution